# Python Packages not showing up after pip install

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       
Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\JOEYCH~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17484/1544913177.py in <module>
----> 1 import basemap

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'basemap'
```

Hi all,

I am new to python and I kept reading other forums but nothing seems to work.

I currently am using a jupyter notebook through anaconda. I am having trouble installing packages.

I have tried creating a new environment, activating that environment and installing packages through the PowerShell terminal. Even though the terminal says the packages (`geopy` and jupyter) are installed when I run `conda` list, I still am getting the no module found error.

I have tried installing the packages directly in jupyter notebook with the following code but I receive the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       
Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\JOEYCH~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11232/996305698.py in <module>
      3 import sys
      4 get_ipython().system('{sys.executable} -m pip install basemap')
----> 5 import basemap

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'basemap
```

I have added the environment to my jupyter notebook and it shows up so I can switch the kernel to the new environment.
Code I used to add my environment to jupyter notebook

````
$ipython kernel install --name "local-venv-kernel" --user```
````

Comment: To help you best it would be good to know if you are using  Windows, Apple or Linux and if you are using the terminal or the Anaconda Navigator.

Comment: I assume it's Windows, from `C:\Users\JOEYCH~1\AppData\Local\`

Comment: yes i have windows

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the get_ipython function. I think you should try

```py
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install basemap
```

OR

```py
import sys
!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} basemap
```

depending if you want to use pip or conda as package manager.

From [From Conda docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html)

--yes:    Do you want to instal Y/N] confirmation.
--prefix: [Specify] Full path to environment location

From [sys doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html)

sys.prefix: Path to environment location.